# On the definition of a real variable

Tags: soft-question, definition

As I was watching a seminar given by Alain Connes at IHÉS, I came to realize I had no idea on how to properly define what a *real variable* is. As far as I can remember, I've never been taught that, and I can't seem to find any answer on the Web.

According to Connes, **a real variable is a map $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is a set.**

Now, Connes believes this widely-accepted definition poses a problem as it comes to the coexistence of *continuous* and *discrete real variable*, which I quite frankly find to be even more puzzling.

Therefore, I reckon one has the following definitions:

- **a real variable is continuous if $f(X)$ has at least the cardinality of the continuum**.
- **a real variable is discrete if $f(X)$ is at most countable**.

Connes' argument is the following: given a set $X$, if $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous real variable, then $\# X \geq \# \mathbb{R}$. Therefore if $g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is another real variable, as $X$ has at least the cardinality of the continuum, which forces $g$ to be a continuous real variable, making it impossible to have coexistence of continuous and discrete real variable.

Therefore, my previous two definitions are misleading. Because, $g$ might actually take one value (send every element of $X$ onto $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ for instance), making it a discrete variable according to my definition.

Hence, how to correctly define what a real variable is? I can't seem to fathom  Connes' definition. Once defined, how would you go at defining the continuous and discrete real variable?

Comment: "which forces $g$ to be a continuous real variable" Why? That $g$ is defined on some "large" set $X$ forces nothing of the sort. The identity function (continuous) and the integer part function (discrete) seem to "coexist" pretty well on $X=\mathbb R$.

Comment: I've noticed that ;). Still, the question remains: **what is a real variable**, or at least, how to interpret it with our general intuition (*"a real variable is $x$ which takes values in a subset of the real line"*).

Comment: To tell you the truth, it is difficult to get what Connes is after, from your post. The objection to the "coexistence" seems just absurd hence I guess there is more to it than this, but.

Comment: Maybe the first couple minutes of this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODAngTW8deg) should suffice to make things a tiny-bit clearer.

Comment: There are tons of omitted context in the talk, but what bothers the author with functions $g:X\to\mathbb R$ such that $g(X)$ is at most countable (which they call *discrete* functions) is that, then, $g^{-1}(\{u\})$ is uncountable for some $u$ in $\mathbb R$. The solution to this fact (why worrisome, they do not really say) is to encode continuous functions as elements of $L^2(\mathbb R)$, discrete functions (viewed as sequences) as elements of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, and to note that, "since there is only one Hilbert space", $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ are isomorphic.

Comment: This seems (to me) more akin to a struggle to define *random variable* than about defining a real variable (where my sympathies are with you, a variable $x$ whose value is known to be a real number).